# How can I make a column thats last in markup flow first on mobile vertically?

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

I got an simple CSS grid that I developed myself, it reminds of Twitter bootstrap. I got an row element and several col elements with their own span size classes.

Below is a simple clean example of my code:

```css
.row{
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.row:after,
.row:before{
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.row:after{
  clear: both;
}

.col{
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 15px;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
}

.span-6{
  width: 50%;
}

@media screen and (max-width:780px){
  .span-md-12{
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col span-6 span-md-12">World</div>
  <div class="col span-6 span-md-12">Hello</div>
</div>
```

I want the Hello to appear before the World statement in my example. It needs to work when the width is 100% on both columns, so float right on the col element won't cut it.

In other words I want to have an CSS class that I can add so columns that appear after in the HTML can flow before the first column. Any idea how I can achieve this?

Edit:
My solution was to add flexbox support in the media query. It seems to have good support for mobiles. See: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing, except my layout is actually based on Bootstrap.  I've asked the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30300499/change-column-order-in-mobile-view  Will watch this question for a solution!

Comment: I think changing the markup is the only way to go with Bootstrap, instead of using floats of course.

Comment: Does not really make any difference if I float right instead of float left when both columns are width: 100%; - Did I miss any thing?

Comment: icethrill: `.span-6{
  width: 50%;
}`

Comment: Yes it works if the columns are width: 50%; But if you noticed my code example I have an special class that makes it width: 100%; I want them to flow vertically in the row. Sorry if I left out that fact in the description.

Comment: I guess the answer is reset floats, display and add a flexbox solution to this. Thanks for your comment! It helped me.