# Bootstrap pull-right and mobile devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have `<h1>` and inside it `<div class="pull-right">` which contains buttons at the same horizontal line with title of the site.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>
            Title
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">...</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">...</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">...</a>
            </div>
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Would it be possible to get the buttons below the title when using mobile devices? For example:

[image: Example 1]

Comment: used proper bootstrap

Comment: Here you have very similar question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404861/bootstrap-3-pull-right-for-col-lg-only

Comment: You can't (or rather shouldn't) nest a div inside an H1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do that because those buttons are not part of your `title` and this would have some SEO drawbacks (Search engines algorithms use contents of `<h1>` element as your first level heading on your page ). instead do this:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1100px){ 
  .pull-right{
    display:inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>Title</h1><!--
        --><div class="pull-right">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">...</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">...</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">...</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This way you have your desired output on mobile devices (Screen width lower than 1100px ) and inline state on devices width screen width higher than that

Comment: Thanks for info about search engines. And this is what I was looking for!

Comment: ur welcome. try to consider SEO in ur design from now on

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can't nest a `div` inside an `h1`. Secondly, why not use the grid system properly?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <div class="pull-right">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">...</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">...</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">...</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your heading inside a `col-sm-12 col-md-5` .

THis would ensure that on small devices, the heading row takes the entire width, thush shifting the buttons below the title div.

For more information, see this : [Responsive Grids: Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Answer (score 0):

Standart bootstrap disable pull-classes on mobile-view. You need manually add to your css next code:

```
@media(max-width:769px) {
  .pull-right {
     float:right!important;
  }
  .pull-left {
     float:left!important;
  }
}
```