# Replace class with another class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one form in which multiple divs are available.But for mobile view i want to remove pull-right class.

So is there any way to achieve it ?

I have removed detail level content but as we can see that one class pull-right which is create an issue for me.

Please let me know if any other information i missed to give here.

```
<form action="http://localhost:8085/email/email_client_area/" accept-charset="utf-8" id="commission_form" method="POST" name="commission_form">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="col-md-12 main-box">
        <header class='main-box-header clearfix'>
            <h2><b>FILTER</b></h2>
        </header>
    </div>  
</div>  
    <div class="col-md-6 pull-right custom_class_1">
            <div class="col-md-12 main-box">
                <header class='main-box-header clearfix'>
            <h2><b>EMAIL INFORMATION</b></h2>
        </header>
        <div class="main-box-body clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-12"></div>
                <center>
                    <div class="col-md-12 margin-t-20 margin-b-20">
                        <button name="action" type="submit" value="save" id="submit" class="btn btn-success" >Search</button>
                    </div>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
 </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: where you want the class

Comment: What have you already try ?

Comment: I dont want that class if current width of window is less than 500 else need to same as it is.

Comment: You can set different CSS rules using media queries

Comment: Use media queries to do that.

Comment: @Satpal media query can't add class.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ  : i have tried to myself to built logic but didnt get working. So i have post here

Comment: add the code you tried

Comment: @Sagar V I have tried to build logic like first get div which have same class from form.But not able to get it

Comment: your problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404861/bootstrap-3-pull-right-for-col-lg-only)

Comment: Down voters, Will you please provide reason like why this question has been downvoted ?

Answer (score 2):

You can set different CSS rules using media queries

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .pull-right {
        /* override the CSS rules*/
    }
}
```

To remove using jQuery use

```
if($(window).width() > 500)
   $('#commission_form .pull-right').removeClass('pull-right').addClass('yournewClass')
```

Comment: This is not working in my case because i want to remove pull-right class.

Comment: ,Thanks but it will remove from entire source but i want to remove only from this form.

Comment: @AnkitDoshi, then use `$('#commission_form .pull-right').removeClass('pull-right').addClass('yournewClass')`

Answer (score 0):

You should remove class pull-right from this div and add to styles:

```
@media(min-width: 768px) { 
  .custom_class_1{
    float: right;
  }
}
```

You can change 768px to other value

Answer (score 0):

you can use JavaScript to do that.

Check the `innerWidth` of window. if it is less than 500, remove the class from the class list

```
if(window.innerWidth<=500){
     document.querySelector(".pull-right").classList.remove(".pull-right");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is Jquery solution to remove class `pull-right`.

```js
if ($(window).width() > 500) {
    $('.main-box-body .pull-right').addClass('pull-right');
} else {
    $('.main-box-body .pull-right').removeClass('pull-right');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12  ">
<form action="http://localhost:8085/email/email_client_area/" accept-charset="utf-8" id="commission_form" method="POST" name="commission_form"><div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="col-md-12 main-box">
        <header class='main-box-header clearfix'>
            <h2><b>FILTER</b></h2>
        </header>
        <div class="main-box-body clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-12"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-12"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-12"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-12"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 pull-right custom_class_1">
                            <div class="col-md-12 main-box">
                            <header class='main-box-header clearfix'>
                        <h2><b>EMAIL INFORMATION</b></h2>
                    </header>
                    <div class="main-box-body clearfix">
                        <div class="col-md-12"></div>
                            <center>
                            <div class="col-md-12 margin-t-20 margin-b-20">
                                <button name="action" type="submit" value="save" id="submit" class="btn btn-success" >Search</button>
                            </div>
                            </center>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of Offsetting will help you in such type of condition. Where you have added pull-right class change that one with "col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6  custom_class_1"

For more info visit here:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

Answer (score 0):

I think , you may use the javascript code for getting the width of the document and then add remover the class as you want .

```
var doc_width  = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
if (doc_width < 767 ) {
    $("div.main-box-body div.pull-right").removeClass('pull-right');
}
```