# Bootstrap 3 disable class for small devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Form class="form-inline center" where class "center" is as following (in style section):

```
.center { text-align: center }
```

But I want this class "center" Not to be in effect on small to very small devices.  Is there Bootstrap 3 syntax for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using just media queries.

Something like,

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {    
   .center {
       text-align : (your preferred style);
    }
}
```

Here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z7DrZ/3/)

Similar question : [Bootstrap, pull-left for small devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329564/bootstrap-pull-left-for-small-devices)

More information about device and screen sizes : http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Jundev.  Thank you very much! I will try your approach and follow the references links.

Comment: One of the references you kindly wrote provided solution to my question. Can I mark your message as the solution to this thread? Or what is the right etiquette for this forum?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Yes, you certainly can mark my solution as accepted, since you are the question owner. You can also upvote a question or answer if you find it informative.

Answer (score 3):

use the `.hidden-xs` and  `.hidden-sm` classes on `<center>` like this:

```
<center class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
```

for more  details check out official documentation here [Bootstrap Responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)